# Checking that limit is $1$ for a function, using Cauchy condition

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Cauchy condition states that the limit for a function exists if:
$\forall \epsilon > 0 \ \ \exists \delta > 0$ s.t. $\forall x \in E$ and $x \neq a$ and $|x-a| < \delta$ then $|f(x)-A|<\epsilon$.

So take the definition of the function like the following: $f(x) = 1$ for $x \in \mathbb{N}$ and $f(x) = 0$ for $x \notin \mathbb{N}$. I am struggling to apply the Cauchy condition here, simply because the limit of the natural numbers is positive infinity, and thus $a = +\infty$, and there is no such $\delta$ s.t. $|x-\infty| < \delta$. What am I missing here?

EDIT: the limit for when the input to the function is natural numbers.

Comment: What is the domain of f? Is N or R?

Comment: If it is $\mathbb{N}$, then how can we have $x \notin \mathbb{N}$. It is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Let $f$ be defined as above over $\mathbb{R}$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. I think we need to find a $\delta > 0$ such that $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, $|x-n| < \delta \implies |f(x) - 1|<\epsilon$.

Comment: problem is $n$ goes to infinity, so we have to find $|x-\infty| < \delta$

Comment: The Cauchy condition makes sense only for points $a$ in the domain, which in this case is $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Why are you trying to apply it to $a = \infty$?

Comment: Sorry, it's reals with infinities.